# Poppy seedlings - dried out or saveable?

Tags: seedlings, greenhouse, poppy

I'm growing some poppies for the first time and they were doing okay until we had a snow storm. Then I noticed they were wilted/dried out. I did some research into the waterbottle greenhouse and they seem to be doing better. They are pushed down a bit today as the picture was taken right after a top watering. Can they be saved? I really need them to be saved and have hope they can as they are still green! [image: gmai]

Some things you should know: 
-This is a grow kit so the soil was a pellet. 
- It lives in a window and will get taken a foot over to a table if it gets too cold.